# Javascript POST/GET Fetch request - need to access data outside of request

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to access the data returned inside my POST request, outside of the request, preferably made available globally so I can access it in other functions. What I'm really trying to do is access specific JSON data and make changes to it via other functions and PUT/GET requests (I'm making a command line guessing game.)

NOTE: I've seen a lot of this same question on here but I can't figure out how any answer pertains to my code/none of the answers are really what i'm looking for. I would like to know what step I'm missing in my own code to help me accomplish this.

Here is my code so far. I know I'm close but I'm stuck at this point.

```
const apiUrl = 'https://word-guessing-game.onrender.com'

let jsondata = "";
    
    async function getJson(url) {
        let response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        });
        let data = await response.json()
        let gameId = data.game.id
        return gameId
    }
    
    async function main() {
        getJson(apiUrl)
            .then(data => console.log(data));
    }
    
    main();
```

Right now I have this setup to just return the game.id, because that's what i'm trying to access with a separate function/get request. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You cant use the result of asynchronous function outside of it in synchronous way.

Comment: then is there a way to set this up so I can access the data returned from my request in another function ?

Comment: yes, you can call your function inside the async function

Comment: call which function?

Comment: Duplicate: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: as I mentioned in my post, Chris, I understand there are plenty of previous questions about this, but I wanted an answer catered to my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `async/await`, why not use it like this:

```
let jsonData = await getJson(apiUrl)
// jsonData will receive the value which getJson is returning
// in this case, the game id.
```

If you must use `.then` syntax, you will have to pass a callback to update the value of jsonData

```
// in getJson function pass another callback
async function getJson(url, cb) {
.
.
.

let data = await response.json()
let gameId = data.game.id
cb(gameId);
```

And your `cb` function can look like this

```
function cb(data) {
  jsonData = data; // same json data declared at the top
}
```

Comment: Just from a technical standpoint, `async`/`await` code *is* using promises, just `await` instead of `.then`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My intention was to highlight the syntactical difference between `async/await` and `.then`. Thanks for pointing out though. I'll update my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can use your async data by another function

```js
const apiUrl = 'https://word-guessing-game.onrender.com'

    
    async function getJson(url) {
        let response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        });
        let data = await response.json()
        let gameId = data.game.id
        return gameId
    }
    
    function processData(data) {
         console.log(data)
    }
    
    async function main() {
        const data = await getJson(url)
        processData(data)
    }
    
    main().then();
```

So as you probably know, the javascript is executed from up to down, so lets see whats happening there:

1. We declare a constant `apiUrl`
2. We declare an async function `getJson`
3. We declare an ordinary function `processData`
4. We declare another async function `main`
5. We not at long last call our main function, which calls `getJson`, where we pass our `apiUrl` as a param. the `await` key allows us to "wait" for the result from the function so we can access it with our `processData` function

PS. `.then()` I used because usually most IDE and inspecting tools are not happy when you call a function which returns a Promise, which you ignore.

Comment: any chance you can walk through whats happening here?

Comment: @sal Consider accepting this answer by clicking the checkmark if this is the most suitable answer